# Lodash: Combine array object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to combine the array with same id for example

```
var student = [{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 2,
   'date': '2019-01-01'
},{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 5,
   'date': '2019-01-01'
},{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 5,
   'date': '2019-03-24'
},{
   'id': 'xx002',
   'code': 'small',
   'item': 2,
   'date': '2019-01-01'
}]

and the output should be.
```

[image]

and when it combine the same id it will added the item and if the date is not the same it should seperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really need lodash, but since it's asked for you can loop using `_.forEach` and then check if we already have the item using `_.find()`

**Snippet** I have also included a non-lodash version:

```js
var students = [{
  'id': 'xx001',
  'code': 'taller',
  'item': 2
}, {
  'id': 'xx001',
  'code': 'taller',
  'item': 5
}, {
  'id': 'xx002',
  'code': 'small',
  'item': 2
}];

const output = [];
_.each(students, x => {
  const existing = _.find(output, {
    id: x.id
  });

  if (existing) {
    existing.item += x.item;
  } else {
    output.push(x);
  }
});

console.info(output);

const students2 = [{
  'id': 'xx001',
  'code': 'taller',
  'item': 2
}, {
  'id': 'xx001',
  'code': 'taller',
  'item': 5
}, {
  'id': 'xx002',
  'code': 'small',
  'item': 2
}];

const output2 = [];
students2.forEach(x => {
  const existing = output2.find(y => y.id === x.id);

  if (existing) {
    existing.item += x.item;
  } else {
    output2.push(x);
  }
});

console.log(output2);


var students3 = [{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 2,
   'date': '2019-01-01'
},{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 5,
   'date': '2019-01-01'
},{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 5,
   'date': '2019-03-24'
},{
   'id': 'xx002',
   'code': 'small',
   'item': 2,
   'date': '2019-01-01'
}]

const output3 = [];
students3.forEach(x => {
  const existing = output3.find(y => y.id === x.id && y.date === x.date);

  if (existing) {
    existing.item += x.item;
  } else {
    output3.push(x);
  }
});

console.log(output3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if sir, if there's a date. i'll try to update my code

Comment: see the image sir?

Comment: Just add the relevant terms to the find query as needed. You have the example code above.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var student = [{
            'id': 'xx001',
            'code': 'taller',
            'item': 2
         },{
            'id': 'xx001',
            'code': 'taller',
            'item': 5
         },{
            'id': 'xx002',
            'code': 'small',
            'item': 2
         }];
        
        
         let idList = Array.from(new Set(student.map(p => p.id)));

         console.log(idList);
         let result = [];

         idList.filter(p => {

            let filteredList =  student.filter(k => p == k.id);
            console.log(filteredList);
            let itemList = filteredList.map(j => j.item);
            let sumItem = itemList.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            result.push({'id': p , 'code' : filteredList[0].code, 'item': sumItem});

         })

         console.log(result);
```

This is result && i don't know what is the code so i ignored
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `_.reduce()`, https://codepen.io/1010543618/pen/VwwgVwm?editors=0010

```js
var student = [{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 2
},{
   'id': 'xx001',
   'code': 'taller',
   'item': 5
},{
   'id': 'xx002',
   'code': 'small',
   'item': 2
}];

var result = _.reduce(student, function(res, stu, index, arr){
  var fstu = _.find(res, function(d){
    return d.id === stu.id;
  });
  if(fstu){
     fstu.item += stu.item;
  }else{
     res.push(_.clone(stu));
  }
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```